# Grouping Period series values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, period

Following on from [Reading CSV file in Pandas with historical dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987699/reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-historical-dates) I have some CSV data in the form:

```
Object,Earliest Date
Object1,01/01/2000
Object2,01/01/1760
Object3,01/01/1520
...
```

which I've now read into Pandas (using Period to handle historical dates) and create a series. I'm trying to bin the series into decades, but stumbling on getting the Period values into the form groupby expects. So far I've tried (where s is the series created from_csv):

```
def dt_parse(s):
  try:
    d,m,y = s.split('/')
    return pd.Period(year=int(y), month=int(m), day=int(d), freq='D')
  except:
    return pd.NaT
s2 = s['Earliest Date'].apply(dt_parse) #Create Period values
pi = pd.PeriodIndex(s2)
decades = pi.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="120M")).count()
```

which fails with:

```
 TypeError: Argument 'labels' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got TimeGrouper)
```

Trying to group on it as a series:

```
 decades = s2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="120M")).count()
```

fails with:

```
 TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Trying to group on it as a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s2)
decades = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="120M", key='Earliest Date')).size()
```

fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_timestamp'
```

Not sure how else to do it ?!

Comment: what does dt_parse do?  I suspect passing `as_index=False` to df.groupby() will do what you want.

Comment: dt_parse returns the date as a Period (see first link). Added as_index=False to the df.groupby call (without the key arg as doesn't seem to apply), now get the same error as with a series (TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages and pandas documentation will be your friends here.

I have no idea whether your date column contain strictly unique dates.  If they are, it's trivial, just use it as the index and you can use `pd.Grouper`.  Otherwise, define your own grouping function:

```
def grouper(ind):
    y = df.loc[ind]['Earliest Date'].year 
    return y - (y % 10)

# I'm assuming that df is the dataframe from pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv")
# and that there's a column named "earliest date" 
# that is a Period or Datetime or something with a year attribute
gb = df.groupby(by=grouper)
print(gb.size())
```

Comment: Wonderful, working now thanks. Quite a deep dive for a first project, definitely back to the docs!