# Pandas OutOfBoundsDatetime when cleaning different date formats with dates before 1677

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, datetime

With Pandas I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531489/converting-different-date-time-formats-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-pandas-dataframe) to clean up dates with a variety of formats. This works perfectly if I filter out the dates that are prior to 1677. However my dates are historic and many date before 1677 so I get an OutOfBoundsDatetime error.

My data contains dates like:

```
27 Feb 1928,
1920,
October 2000,
1500,
1625,
Mar 1723
```

I can see a [reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987699/reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-historical-dates) to using pd.Period but I don't know how to apply it to my case as the dates need to be cleaned first before I can adapt this sample

My code to clean the dates is:

```
df['clean_date'] = df.dates.apply(
lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

df
```

I would like help to convert and clean my dates including the historic dates. Grateful for assistance with this.

Comment: what is your goal? You can't have a Pandas Series of `datetime64[ns]` dtype with values before `1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225` or after `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807` - they will be wrapped. You can have a Period dtype though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is clearly stated in the [online documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) you can't have values of `datetime64[ns]` dtype that are **not** falling into `['1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225', '2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807']`.

But you can have such dates as Period dtype.

**Sample input dataset:**

```
In [156]: df
Out[156]:
           Date
0   27 Feb 1928
1          1920
2  October 2000
3          1500
4          1625
5      Mar 1723

In [157]: df.dtypes
Out[157]:
Date    object
dtype: object
```

**Solution:**

```
In [158]: df["new"] = pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period(d, freq="D") for d in df.Date])
```

**Result:**

```
In [159]: df
Out[159]:
           Date         new
0   27 Feb 1928  1928-02-27
1          1920  1920-01-01
2  October 2000  2000-10-01
3          1500  1500-01-01
4          1625  1625-01-01
5      Mar 1723  1723-03-01

In [160]: df.dtypes
Out[160]:
Date       object
new     period[D]
dtype: object

In [161]: df["new"].dt.year
Out[161]:
0    1928
1    1920
2    2000
3    1500
4    1625
5    1723
Name: new, dtype: int64
```